# can you help translate this painting caligraphy

Tags: translation

[image: here is the entire picture/painting[![This one is smaller from the bottom left hand side. This part says the location that is as much as I can read from it. the calligraphy is amazing and very old]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrEm8.jpg)[[image: .]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGXHk.png)I recently purchased this painting and it has great calligraphy, I would love to know more about the story behind the painting

I recently purchased this painting and it has great calligraphy, I would love to know more about the story behind the painting

Comment: been trying Google translate and it gives me various names or meaning but nothing significant

Comment: Can you provide the image of the painting as well? I think it might help, along with a clearer image of the seal (which would help with identifying the author/painter).

Comment: Thanks I posted some more picture Michael

Comment: By the way, nobody's going to translate that poem for you. We expect you to do the minimum amount of research, and you have the transcription of the text already. Also, please add non-answer content, like new pictures, to your question - don't post answers.

Comment: Drooze, I am very new to the site and I have done a lot of research on the painting where people wanted to charge me cash to put the writing together for me. I do greatly appreciate the help and everyone's comments. I do have another part to decipher

Comment: If you have done research, post the results of your research in the question. At the moment we only see your photographs, not your attempts at deciphering. Also, I hope you’re not charging other people for the results you get here.

Comment: Droooze, who will I charge for a personal painting? confused by your comment. please explain. I love this painting and my home is covered with antiques my hubby and I collect. As for what I got from google translate is the rubber has a scatter of the sacred me. Feng Xingshi returned to the three counts to practice the law. I am not a big collector but I love vintage items and knowing a little history about it is good. I try looking the calligraphy up and I keep getting pieces of a puzzle but not much, thank you. There is also no reference point to go and compare the calligraphy too.

Answer (score 3):

the calligraphy is the poem "趙伯駒六馬圖歌" by emperor 乾隆 (1736-1795).

read top to bottom, right to left:

> 平川苜蓿豐且滋﹒清泉映帶沙岡披﹒戎人習馬知馬性
>
> 此䖏調馬實所宜﹒牽者樴者二皆駵﹒白駒黒鬛緤栁枝
>
> 昻蔵翹足驪其色﹒一戎跨背鞍不施﹒紫騮廻首嘶厥匹
>
> 有駓齕草意自怡﹒驥不稱力稱其徳﹒况復一一皆英竒
>
> 作者寓意應有在﹒夏官遺法誰深知﹒即今大宛致汗血
>
> 骨格皆合圖中姿﹒亦不渥洼詡作瑞﹒亦不交河資興師
>
> 迥立閶闔詄蕩蕩﹒欲起王孫走筆為

the last "column" stated the date as

> 辛巳首夏御題

the first month of summer of the year 1761.

[image]

Comment: sigh 乾隆's poem is really mediocre.

Comment: well, he had the largest quantity of poems in chinese. and, he preferred to use rare characters, as an indication of his knowledge of the culture, like it or not :)

Comment: Excellent work, as always! My GF was stumped, she could not read it!

Comment: @pedroski, it's not difficult: read and recognise a few characters then google it :) e.g. "戎人習馬知馬性", imo, is easy to read, from the original picture.

Comment: @Pedroski exactly, how else do you think I manage to read blurry seals :)

Comment: Well, I would say, you guys are somewhat more intelligent than I! :)